In SSRS how can you make the y-axis height be dynamic on the number of bars in the graph?
I would like to have the height be dynamic according to how many bars are displayed in the graph of an ssrs report.  I've set the width and height property of the chart to be 7in, and 5in.  The graph looks proportional if I have several bars, but if I only have one bar its still the same height. Its not that bad, but it would be nice to control that a bit more by the number of bars.  Is there an auto setting I'm missing? Or is that something I need to write an expression for?  Thanks!

As far as I know, this is not possible. The size properties of most report items do no accept expressions, only literal values.

Thanks for the response.  I agree, I don't see how this is possible.
